# Added a global width I want one specific element to exceed that width limit

Tags: html, css

I declared a global width. But I want one specific element to go over that limit but it doesn't seem to work. It is a text with a background image. I just want the background image to go over that limit but when I widen the element, the text goes over the width aswell.

I tried to manually extend the width of the element by width:150% but the texts goes over the limit aswell

```css
html, body {
    font-size: 1em;
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 1222px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}.wrapperbody {
    background-image:url("background.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperbody">
    <div>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to expand the background image of a text but the whole text gets expanded.

Comment: Well h-tags are block elements so they will take up the whole width of the wrapper they are in. I would suggest targeting the h1 directly and giving it a width.

Comment: You actually added the width to body element and now you want a wider element? How come, are you sure you posted the correct code? This really has no sense.

Comment: Maybe the questions was incoherent. I setup a global width to lineup the text on the whole website. The background image should be wider than the text so it kinda looks like this website : https://www.lidl-reisen.de/dsfgh

Answer (score 1):

One should never compose the page that way, the width should be declared to sections instead. That is the reason you cannot set the background proper way and you will get more troubles later on.

Anyhow, if you still choose to keep such layout, than you gotta do some tricks as following:

```css
html,
body {
    font-size: 1em;
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapperbody {
    margin-top: 10%;
 position: relative;
}

.wrapperbody > * {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.wrapperbody::before {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
 content: '';
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 left: calc((100vw - 200px) / -2);
 right: calc((100vw - 200px) / -2);
 bottom: 0;
 background: none red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperbody">
    <div>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d24atuvp/2/)

Once again, please consider changing the layout.